# How to export many variables and functions from global environment to foreach loop?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, global-variables, doparallel

How can I export the global environment for the beginning of each parallel simulation in foreach? The following code is part of a function that is called to run the simulations.

```
  num.cores <- detectCores()-1
  cluztrr <- makeCluster(num.cores)
  registerDoParallel(cl = cluztrr)

  sim.result.list <- foreach(r = 1:simulations, 
      .combine = list,
      .multicombine = TRUE, 
      ) %dopar% {

          #...tons of calculations using many variables...

          list(vals1,
               vals2,
               vals3)
  }
 stopCluster(cluztrr)
```

Is it necessary to use .export with a character vector  of *every* variable and function that I use? Would that be slow in execution time?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: "cluztrr" rulezzz :-)))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the foreach loop is in the global environment, variables should be exported automatically. If not, you can use `.export = ls(globalenv())` (or `.GlobalEnv`).

For functions from other packages, you just need to use the syntax `package::function`.

Comment: How do you call functions that are not part of packages but that are defined in the global environment? @F. Privé

Answer (score 12):

The "If [...] in the *global* environment, ..." part of [F. Privé reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45768361/1072091) is very important here.  The foreach framework will only identify global variables in that case.  It will *not* do so if the `foreach()` call is done within a function.

However, if you use the [doFuture](https://cran.r-project.org/package=doFuture) backend (disclaimer: I'm the author);

```
library("doFuture")
registerDoFuture()
plan(cluster, workers = cl)
```

global variables *that are needed* will be automatically identified and exported (which is then done by the [future](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future) framework and not the foreach framework).  Now, if you rely on this, and don't explicitly specify `.export`, then your code will only work with `doFuture` and none of the other backends.  That's a decision you need to make as a developer.

Also, automatic exporting of globals is neat, but be careful that you know how much is exported; exporting too many too large objects can be quite costly and introduce lots of overhead in your parallel code.

Comment: Does it also export variables in the parent environment? :-)

Comment: Yes. It does it by taking an "optimistic" approach allowing for false positives, that is, it is ok to find globals that are not really globals (may happen in e.g. non-standard evaluation). Occasionally, code is such that it misses true positives and then you (obviously) get a runtime error. In such cases one can easily guide it - see future vignette 'Common Issues with Solutions' (https://cran.r-project.org/package=future) for how.